# Bash script not executing on startup

Tags: bash, cron, ubuntu-18.04

I used crontab to run a bash script once a day (at midnight). This worked successfully, but I didn't really think it through enough to realise that the script would not run if my computer happened to be off at midnight (or even asleep).

So I think that I have to keep the crontab entry (in case my computer is on) but I also want to make the bash script execute on startup (in case my computer was off) so that I have covered all my bases.

I saw online that to have my script execute on startup I should edit my `/etc/rc.local` file. My file now contains:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                    
bash /home/me/code.sh
exit 0
```

and my permissions are `-rwxr-xr-x`.

However, the script does not execute on startup. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you created the /etc/rc.local yourself right? AFAIK there isn't any in Ubuntu 18.04 anymore (as it is depricated). That's probably why it's not executed.

@reboot in crontab might be a possible solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Anacron is the answer for your problem. This is cron like system created exactly for tasks on machines not always on.
https://linux.die.net/man/5/anacrontab